# SAML 2.0 authentication request to Identity Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, saml-2.0

How to generate SAML 2.0 authentication request to Identity Authentication in ASP.NET MVC?

UPDATED:  I have tried  Sustainsys.Saml2. Part of webconfig file is given below. When I try to sign in I get exception "The system cannot find the file specified.".

```
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId="http://localhost:58917/Saml2" returnUrl="http://localhost:58917/">
    <identityProviders>
        <add entityId="~/App_Data/metadata.xml" signOnUrl="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
            <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/stubidp.sustainsys.com.cer"/>
        </add>
    </identityProviders>
    <!--<federations>
        <add metadataLocation="http://localhost:58917/Federation" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"/>
    </federations>-->
    <!--<serviceCertificates>
        <add fileName="~/App_Data/Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx"/>
    </serviceCertificates>-->
</sustainsys.saml2>
```

Comment: do you have certificate file `stubidp.sustainsys.com.cer` under `App_Data` folder?

Comment: Yes, I missed certificate file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://github.com/onelogin/dotnet-saml) and you can follow there [MVC sample application](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Samples/SampleMvcApplication)

> The MVC package contains an MVC controller that will be accessible in
>   your application just by installing the package in the application.
>   For MVC applications a controller is preferred over using the
>   authentication module as it integrates with MVC’s error handling.
>
> Nuget Package to use: [Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc/)
>
> See [Configuration](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/configuration.html) for information about how to configure the
>   `web.config` file.

**Update:** Make sure that certificate file `stubidp.sustainsys.com.cer` under `App_Data` folder

Comment: I have already gone through that link. However I could not implement due to lack of documentation.

Comment: Update the question with what you did and where was you issue